# Weka string attributes for sparse ARFF file

Tags: file-format, weka, sparse-matrix, arff

I am trying to use Weka for text classification.
For this purpose, it makes sense to use the sparse ARFF data file format.
Using Weka 3.7.2, I tried:

1. Transforming a text directory to an Instances object using 
   [TextDirectoryLoader](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/core/converters/TextDirectoryLoader.html).
2. Translating the strings resulting from the former stage to numbers using [StringToWordVector](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/filters/unsupervised/attribute/StringToWordVector.html).

The first stage worked fine. The second stage caused a problem, described this way in the
[Weka's ARFF file format specification](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29):

> Warning: There is a known problem saving SparseInstance objects from datasets that have string attributes. In Weka, string and nominal data values are stored as numbers; these numbers act as indexes into an array of possible attribute values (this is very efficient). However, the first string value is assigned index 0: this means that, internally, this value is stored as a 0. When a SparseInstance is written, string instances with internal value 0 are not output, so their string value is lost (and when the arff file is read again, the default value 0 is the index of a different string value, so the attribute value appears to change).

The ARFF format suggests this solution:

> To get around this problem, add a dummy string value at index 0 that is never used whenever you declare string attributes that are likely to be used in SparseInstance objects and saved as Sparse ARFF files.

I am trying to do just that - add a dummy string. I have failed to do this manually (by editing the ARFF file). Can anyone who has done this already post an example - either of a program segment doing this, a properly modified ARFF file, or some other way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Weka printing sparse arff file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839986/weka-printing-sparse-arff-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do NOT edit the arff file directly.

I just answered a similar question here:
[Weka printing sparse arff file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839986/weka-printing-sparse-arff-file)

Use the same code example.