# Weka printing sparse arff file

Tags: java, weka, sparse-matrix, arff

I was trying out the sparse representation of the arff file as shown [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html). In my program I am able to print the the class label "B" but for some reason it is not printing "A".

```
    attVals = new FastVector();
    attVals.addElement("A");
    attVals.addElement("B");
    atts.addElement(new Attribute("class", attVals));

    vals[index] = attVals.indexOf("A");
```

The output for the program is like -

```
 {0 6,2 8}      ---  I should get {0 6,2 8,3 A}
```

But when I do

```
vals[index] = attVals.indexOf("B");
```

I get proper output -

```
 {0 6,2 8,3 B}
```

For some reason it is not taking the index 0. Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very popular problem. The Sparse format by definition does not store 0 values.

Weka [ARFF format page](http://weka.wikispaces.com/ARFF+%28stable+version%29#Sparse%20ARFF%20files) clearly says that:

> Warning: There is a known problem saving SparseInstance objects from
>   datasets that have string attributes. In Weka, string and nominal data
>   values are stored as numbers; these numbers act as indexes into an
>   array of possible attribute values (this is very efficient). However,
>   the first string value is assigned index 0: this means that,
>   internally, this value is stored as a 0. When a SparseInstance is
>   written, string instances with internal value 0 are not output, so
>   their string value is lost (and when the arff file is read again, the
>   default value 0 is the index of a different string value, so the
>   attribute value appears to change). To get around this problem, add a
>   dummy string value at index 0 that is never used whenever you declare
>   string attributes that are likely to be used in SparseInstance objects
>   and saved as Sparse ARFF files.

You have to put a dummy attribute in the first place. Just modify your code to:

```
attVals = new FastVector();
attVals.addElement("dummy");
attVals.addElement("A");
attVals.addElement("B");
```

Let me know if you need any further help.